# Handling tabRefreshed event in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, console, refresh

I am in need of refreshing the LWC component when user clicks on 'Refresh Tab' action in a console application. I coundn't find a way of handling the tabRefreshed event in LWC components.

**1.** What I am planning to do is to add an aura component to handle the event as shown below.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />  
    <aura:handler event="lightning:tabRefreshed" action="{! c.onTabRefreshed }"/>
</aura:component>
```

and then in the controller,

```
({
   onTabRefreshed : function(component, event, helper) {
       console.log("Tab Refreshed");
       var refreshedTabId = event.getParam("tabId");
       var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
       workspaceAPI.getTabInfo({
            tabId : refreshedTabId
       }).then(function(response) {


            //--Fire pubSub event    


       });
   }
})
```

Then, handle that event in the LWC and then call refreshApex event.

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
```

**2.** What will be the advantage if I wrap the LWC in Aura component? I don't like to mix LWC with Aura.

I hope both will work but what is the recommended approach?

Comment: I'm running into this issue on a project now, and this question is almost 1.5 years old. Any update on this?